# How to figure out error from log

Tags: ios, objective-c

My project is crashing and pointed to the following line in `main.m` file

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

And showing log in console as following from which I couldn't find file or line number to fix the bug.

```
2014-07-23 13:24:08.564 Test Project[11312:707] Starting app
2014-07-23 13:24:08.577 Test Project[11312:707] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
2014-07-23 13:24:08.969 Test Project[11312:707] get pin pass
2014-07-23 13:24:08.973 Test Project[11312:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x36c5f88f 0x33076259 0x36bb723d 0x987e7 0x32892933 0x36c33a33 0x36c33699 0x36c3226f 0x36bb54a5 0x36bb536d 0x34d7c439 0x34e5ecd5 0x93679 0x935c8)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

There is a point `*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]:` but which is used more and more in all files.

How to fix this bug.

Comment: Run Xcode instrument Profile with zombie.

Comment: Have you added an exception breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

Your logs prints "get pin pass" so find this text in your project and see where you are calling [NSArray objectAtIndex:] on an empty array. The array doesn't have any objects in it. Do this to avoid crash

```
if(array.count > index){
  [NSArray objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I understand this but many times many array are used. Which array is it. How this find.

Answer (score 0):

Add an exception breakpoint, which will stop on the line of coding causing the exception.

Instructions are here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html